# C++ constructor template specialization

Tags: c++, templates, constructor, template-specialization

I'm trying to create a specialized constructor for `std::string` arguments, but the other one is always used when I call it with a string argument.

```
struct Literal : Expression
{    
    template <typename V>
    Literal(V val)
    {
        value = val;
    }
};

template <>
Literal::Literal(std::string const& val)
{
    value = val.c_str();
}
```

It doesn't matter if both are defined inside the class, both outside the class, or like in the posted example only the specialization is defined outside the class: When called with `std::string`, the assignment `value = val` gives a compiler error.

How do I correctly specialize this constructor template for `std::string`?

Comment: You didn't declare `value`. This is the error you'll get: _main.cpp:12:9: error: 'value' was not declared in this scope
         value = val;_

Comment: @HenriqueBarcelos `ATL::CComVariant value` is declared in `Expression`. I only posted the relevant template stuff for brevity.

Comment: I'm assuming `value` is defined in the base class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't.

You should overload the *constructor*: `Literal(const std::string&)`, which you can do in the `struct` declaration.

The compiler always tries to match non-template overloads before template ones.

Comment: There's no edit and I don't see a non-template constructor?

Comment: My confusion is this: he only has the one constructor, and it's templated, he's attempting to specialize it, so the compiler's choice is between the in-class templated declaration/definition or the specialization of it - where is the non-template overload opportunity?

Comment: @kfsone I just added a non-templated overload and it works now.

Comment: @kfsone You add simply a second constructor to the class that isn't templated and accepts a `const std::string&`.

Answer (score 6):

According to the [standard, 14.8.2.1](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.deduct.call) Deducing template arguments from a function call [temp.deduct.call] where `P` is the template parameter and `A` is the function-call argument in that position:

> 2 If P is not a reference type:
>
> If A is an array type, the pointer type produced by the array-to-pointer = standard conversion ([conv.array]) is used in place of A for type deduction; otherwise,
>
> If A is a function type, the pointer type produced by the function-to-pointer standard conversion ([conv.func]) is used in place of A for type deduction; otherwise,
>
> *If A is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of A's type are ignored for type deduction.*
>
> If P is a cv-qualified type, the top-level cv-qualifiers of P's type are ignored for type deduction. If P is a reference type, the type referred to by P is used for type deduction. [...]

So given

```
std::string s{"hello"};
const std::string& sr{s};
Literal l(sr);
```

`A` (sr) is `const std::string&` but the constness is not considered, so the compiler considered `std::string`. This matches your

```
template <typename V>
Literal(V val)
{
    value = val;
}
```

and so it uses this specialization. If you had specialized

```
template<>
Literal(std::string val)
```

the compiler would find this specialization, and this is probably what you will have to do and use move semantics.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

struct S {
    template<typename T>
    S(T t) { std::cout << "T t\n"; }

    std::string value_;
};

template<>
S::S(std::string value) {
    std::cout << "string\n";
    value_ = std::move(value);
}

template<>
S::S(const std::string&) {
    std::cout << "const string&\n";
}

int main() {
    S s1(42);

    std::string foo{"bar"};
    const std::string& foor = foo;
    S s2(foo);
    S s3(foor);
}
```

http://ideone.com/eJJ5Ch

Comment: Thanks, this is a correct answer! However, I didn't have that kind of problem using gcc toolchain. Only when porting to clang, I had to search for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Many times, when overload is a solution, people try to define full specialization. But overload could be a much better solution. In your case, I would create a new constructor with the string parameter.
Remember that only base template is considered in overload resolution. The following article is a good reference to understand this idea:
http://www.gotw.ca/publications/mill17.htm

UPDATE:

Anyway, to improve my answer, you could try the following base template constructor:

```
template <typename V>
Literal(V const& val)
{
    value = val;
}
```